# How can I access a variable across script tasks within a package?

Tags: ssis

I have got two SSIS script tasks within a Sequence Container. I have declared variable **`StartTime`** in `Script Task 1`. I want to use this variable in `Script Task 2`.

Is it possible to access the variable `StartTime` within `Script Task 2`? How can I access the variable?

Comment: I'm using Script Task on the Control Flow - so within 1-sequence container I have two script task

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create variables in SSIS packages, you can define the scope of the variable. This scope defines which tasks on the Control Flow have visibility to the variables.

#### Sample package describing variable scopes:

Here is a sample SSIS package.

I have created a package with a sequence container and two Script Tasks within it. I have created four variables under different scope.

If you want to view all the variables defined under different scopes, you need to check the fourth button on the `Variables` pane. The option is indicated by the arrow in the screenshot.

Here is how the variables work in each of these scope:

**`StartTime_Package`** - This variable is declared under the scope `MyPackage`, which also happens to be the package name. This is the top level scope. This variable will be visible to all the tasks on the Control Flow.

**`StartTime_Sequence`** - This variable is declared under the scope `Sequence Container`, which is the given name of the sequence container task. This variable will be visible only to the Sequence container and the tasks within the sequence container.

**`StartTime_Task1`** - This variable is declared under the scope `Script Task 1`, which is the given name of the first script task within the sequence container. This variable will be visible only to the first script task and no other tasks.

**`StartTime_Task2`** - This variable is declared under the scope `Script Task 2`, which is the given name of the second script task within the sequence container. This variable will be visible only to the second script task and no other tasks.

[image: Variables Scope]

#### How can I check if a task can access a variable or not?

Here is an easier way to identify if a particular task can access a variable or not. Let's uncheck the third option on the Variables pane.

Click on the `Script Task 1`. You will notice that the variable `StartTime_Task2` is not displayed on the Variables pane because `Script Task 1` does not have visibility to it.

Likewise, you can click on the task and verify which variables it can access.

You have to decide what the scope of the variable should be based on your requirements. If you are going to share the value of a variable across tasks, it is safe to declare it at the topmost package level scope.

If you are very sure that you will not access a certain variable outside of a particular task, it is safe to declare it at that task's scope level.

[image: Scope of the variables.]

#### How to read a variable or write a value to variable using Script Task?

Double-click on the Script task, it will bring the Script Task Editor. You have to determine whether you just want to read the variable values or modify it within the task. I am going to modify a variable value and then display the value in a message box. To do that, I have to pick a variable that is already declared on the package and provide the script task the read and write access. Click the Ellipsis button against the `ReadWriteVariables` property

[image: Script Task Editor]

Select Variables will list the variables (both system and user level) to which the script task has access to. I am going to pick `StartTime_Package` variable.

[image: Select Variables]

You can see the variable now listed in the property. You can select multiple variables to. Click Edit Script so we can modify the C# code to write a value to the variable and then read it.

[image: Edit Script]

Paste the following code into the Script Task. First line assigns the value, here I am just adding 7 days to today's date. Second line displays the value of the variable in a message box.

```
public void Main()
{
    Dts.Variables["StartTime_Package"].Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["StartTime_Package"].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

[image: Script Task code]

If we run the package, it will display the value in message box. The package was executed on November 1, 2012 and you can that the package is displaying the modified value of November 8, 2012.

[image: Message box]

Hope that gives you an idea about variables scope within SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the scope of the variable (StartTime) is Package - that should do. Variable is available for use across the package.

In the first script task, add your variable as a Readwrite variable and maybe assign some value in the script.

In the second script task also, add it as a read or readwrite variable and you can reference it there.